# Positioning axes in matplotlib in physical coordinates

Tags: matplotlib

One can set the position of an Axes in figure coordinates in matplotlib using the following command

```
ax.set_position([left, bottom, width, height])
```

Is there any way I can set this using physical coordinates, and not figure units? When plotting I can achieve this by setting the transform to the fig.dpi_scale_trans, but I don't see how I can do that here. I can of course get the figure coordinates and then compute the corresponding coordinates, but I would like it to update when the figure size changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the axes position in absolute units, e.g. inches, you can override the axes locator with an `AnchoredSizeLocator` from the toolkits module.
E.g. to get an axes 1 inch away from the lower left corner and 3 inches wide and high:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import AnchoredSizeLocator

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

# Coordinates in inches, left, bottom, width, height
coords_inches = [1,1,3,3]
axes_locator = AnchoredSizeLocator(coords_inches, "100%", "100%",
                                   loc="center",
                                   bbox_transform= fig.dpi_scale_trans,
                                   borderpad=0)

ax.set_axes_locator(axes_locator)

plt.show()
```